# Laravel 4 Conditional Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to be able to specify conditions on a relationship (one-to-many).

Example being; We have a Post which has many Comments, but I only want the Posts with Comments made by User A and then return the Post object(s).

The only way I can currently think of doing this is with a Fluent query, which wouldn't return the Post object I desire!

EDIT:

The comment **has** to of been made by User A. The relationship of the User who made the Comment to Post isn't a direct one. It would go through the Comment table.

RE EDIT:

Would it also be possible to say have distinct Posts? Rather than return 3 of the same Post Object?

Comment: you can try this `$post=Posts::with('comments')->where('user_id','=',$user_id)->get()` this will return with data from `post and comments table` only for particular user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query relationships. You would end up with something like this:

```
$postsWithComments = $user->posts()->has('comments', '>=', 1)->get();
```

Here is an extract from documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

**Querying Relations**

When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship. For example, you wish to pull all blog posts that have at least one comment. To do so, you may use the has method:

***Checking Relations When Selecting***

```
$posts = Post::has('comments')->get();
```

***You may also specify an operator and a count:***

```
$posts = Post::has('comments', '>=', 3)->get();
```

Comment: OP wants to filter the Posts so he only gets those with Comments made by a specific User.

Comment: This should do what expected then.

Comment: Well it was straight out from documentation. You have to be able to learn from these kind of examples. In any case I added an example of how it might look like in the end.

Comment: Yeah, as said by @cuewizchris I need the one's made by a specific User. Editting original post.

Comment: Already covered that with the first code example. ;) Good luck in your project. @cuewizchris thanks :)

Comment: This would only return Post's with a Comment count >= 3. Not specific Comments. I've already looked at doing it this way and it clonked me in the face! :D

EDIT: I see what your doing now! My bad. Have my upvote!

Comment: Thanks. I will return to this question after work to answer your question in more detail. ;) Good luck

Comment: Re edited again, what you've said already has helped. Just a little something else would be a bonus! Teehee!